# Tweak Firefox AwesomeBar to be more like Chrome's Omnibar

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, awesomebar, address-bar

Do you know a good way to replicate (more or less) the behavior of Google Chrome's omnibar within Firefox?

I'm especially interested in a way to have Firefox suggest the root of the website when I type, instead of a random page I have visited a bit more often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Omnibar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/omnibar/)** - Firefox Addon

[image]

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for (still the same behavior), but I couldn't find anything else. Too bad :(

Comment: i know it is not exactly like Google's Omnibar, but if all browsers would have the very same features, what would happen to our beloved browser wars? :)

Comment: Yeah, guess so! Damn!