# How do I keep the keyword.url setting in Firefox to the default when you restart the browser without deleting prefs.js?

Tags: firefox, awesomebar

I am on the latest version of Firefox (not beta or anything like that) and currently my `keyword.url` is stuck on `search.google.com` (which I don't remember setting even though the `about:config` says it's a user setting.

How to set it back to default and keep it at the default when I reset my browser?  I do not want to delete `prefs.js` as I do not want to go through setting up all the extension settings I have **just** to have my location bar search Google (if this is the only way then I'll stick with searching from the search bar instead).

I've checked all my extensions that may affect the location bar but could not find anything that says it would change the default search engine for this.  I've also tried to open the `prefs.js` in WordPad or Notepad, but it just ends up freezing when trying to edit it at all (yes, the browser is closed at the time).  I also deleted the `prefs-1.js` file (along with 2 others) that were older (after trying to rename those to `prefs.js` and see if this corrects it.  It might have but had such old extension settings that I went back to my latest `prefs.js` with this one issue instead of the issue of setting back up a ton of extensions.

I can give any other information if needed, someone please help me fix this issue if possible.

Comment: I'm confused. Can't you just change the setting using the about:config page?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I just settled for the answer on this page:

[Tweak Firefox AwesomeBar to be more like Chrome's Omnibar](https://superuser.com/questions/41745/tweak-firefox-awesomebar-to-be-more-like-chromes-omnibar)

I love different Chrome features, so I just installed this instead of playing around for hours or waiting on people to answer my question.

If anyone would still like to suggest anything that's fine.